# Components that best seperate two classes

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I have data that can be classified into two classes, and I would like a data reduction method that best separates the two classes. I understand LDA is an option, but the problem with LDA that it would only return one component (i.e 1 predictor) given that there are only two classes. I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the data into multiple components that best separate the two classes.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

LDA (linear discriminant analysis) is a classification tool. It is a complement to data reduction. It is separate... Reducing the number of numeric features into just a few factors can be achieved in a number of ways. If you are fine with looking at linear transformations only, *principal component analysis* is an option. If you want to compress the data in nonlinear ways, more advanced methods of image processing / signal processing / machine learning can be applied.

LDA is certainly not the best way to summarize the data. But it is a surprisingly accurate classification tool, despite its simplicity.

Comment: Hi Stans. I'm aware of that. My question is how do I get to reduce the between group variance rather than the within group variance into multiple components. PCS works on the within group variance. LDA does something similar but the problem is that it would output one component rather than multiple. So basically I'm wondering if there is a method to that reduces the data to components that best explain the BETWEEEN group variance.

Comment: You cannot "reduce" the between-group variance. The between-group variance of variable X is defined as Var[ E[X | Group] ], irrespective of any modeling endeavors you engage in. Which mathematical problem are you trying to solve? I think we are just having slight miscommunication. Thank you.